# Parse iOS framework causing memory crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've used Xcode's zombie debugger and managed to find this flag upon launch: [image: screenie]
This crashed the app, and re-recording from Instruments caused the same result. Relaunching the app from the device made the app launch without a crash and subsequent launches from Instruments resulted in normal operation without flags or crashes.

Can anyone make sense of this or advise? I'm getting a number of "heap corruption" crashes in production. The reports are limited to a handful of users, but I'm afraid that number is growing.

[image]

It looks like the Parse SDK's latest release notes (1.15.1) addresses this:

> -Adds polygonal queries
>
> -Fixes memory leaks related with PFCommandCache

But my crash reports are coming from builds with this SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

The Parse team has responded saying that a fix for this is coming to a new SDK release soon. :)

Comment: 1.15.2 published yesterday: `Fixes issue related to heap corruption (#1170)`